# Converting date-time format and querying based on a date condition in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, datatable, format

I have around 20,000 entries in a SQL table for which a date column is of the form 
YYYY-MM-DD HH-SS. I would like to convert this format to a YYYY-MM-DD format so I can run  a query on all of the entries that will count the number of entries based on 
a) the month under which they fall
b) the day
I'm new to SQL and not sure if there is a way to loop through all of the entries and check based on the required criteria; and as such, would greatly appreciate any help.
I unfortunately, cannot send a screenshot of the table since the data is classified.

Comment: The fact that the data is classified does not justify the lack of details.  Create dummy tables, columns, data that illustrates what you are trying to do, and post that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the data in the table.  Most databases have `year()` and `month()` functions, so you could do:

```
select year(datecol), month(datecol), count(*)
from sqltable
group by year(datecol), month(datecol)
order by year(datecol), month(datecol);
```

If these specific functions are not available, then I'm sure your database supports something similar.